# Teamcity: Simulating click on Procceed jQuery Button to create .BuildServer in bash

Tags: jquery, bash, curl, click, simulate

I am trying to automate the installation of teamcity in bash.
Like full automation, just have to login.

My problem is that .Buildserver is only created once you click the Procceed Button, and I don't know how to do this in bash.

Is there any way to simulate a click on it in bash ?
Maybe with a curl request ?
I don't think the TeamCity API has this function...

Please help.

I set up an instance so you can see how it looks.. please don't click on Procceed... as others won't be able to see the procceed if you do so..

http://52.24.198.58:8111/mnt

Added page source at pastebin.com/EanC8RkS

Comment: Why don't you inspect the HTTP requests sent after you click on "Proceed"?

Comment: I did.. but it somehow doesn't work... Even installed firebug, clicked the button, exported as curl, no luck :/